# Get location of variable in Microsoft Excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

As an Excel beginner, I opened a sheet which contain a cell where we can see `=myVariable` as the formula. What is `myVariable`, and how can I locate it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`myVariable` is almost certainly a named range. Use the Name Manager on the `Formulas` ribbon to find out where it is in the workbook. Name Manager can also be accessed by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.

[image]

[image]